# Discrete Convolution Sum of two piecewise sequences

Tags: convolution

Assume I have the following two sequences :
$$
x[n]=\begin{cases}
\alpha&\text{if $a\leq n\leq b$}\\ \\
0&\text{if otherwise}
\end{cases}
\qquad
\text{and}
\qquad
h[n]=\begin{cases}
\beta&\text{if $c\leq n\leq d$}\\ \\
0&\text{if otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
I was wondering in this case if the convolution :
$$
(x*h)[n]=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}x[k]h[n-k]
$$
has a specific form applicable for these two piecewise sequences.

I have seen on the internet something like :
$$
(x * h)[n]=\sum_{k=\max (a, n-d)}^{\min (b, n-c)} x[k] h[n-k] .
$$
However, I can not confirm if this is true. I hope someone can provide a proper proof and thank you very much.

Comment: Attention, an answer has been found here : https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/73538/discrete-convolution-of-two-piecewise-sequences-having-this-specific-form